# How to avoid concurrent webservice calls?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, concurrency

I have a Spring Web flow application running on Weblogic 10. In current application, on load of the Page A , we are making an ajax call , which in the back end makes a webservice call WEBSVCA. On the submission of the same page,we have another webservice call being made WEBSVCB. The application requires that WEBSVCA call should always be made and completed before WEBSVCB call starts. But sometimes, when the user submits the page very fast, WEBSVCA response has not comeback yet and the call to WEBSVCB fails because of the concurrent call.

In order to resolve the above problem, I was planning to implement BlockingQueue for the webservice call status. In this case, the response from the WEBSVCA can be used as Producer and before the call to WEBSVCB is made we can check the queue as consumer.

**Is is this the best approach or there could be a simpler approach than this??**

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user can't progress to the next page before WEBSVCA has finished, then it shouldn't be an ajax call - so you could just do it as part of the page load.

Or, disable the submit button by default, then only enable it when the ajax callback succeeds.

Comment: WEBSVCA is time consuming and to improve the application performance we had put it is as ajax , as there are lot of fields which need to be filled in the Page A. So most of the time when the user fills the details in the page in the front end, the call to WEBSVCA is completed. And then when the user submits the page the WEBSVCB it is successful.

Comment: How about my second suggestion then?

Comment: I have been thinking of something on similar lines, and will implement the same if nothing better comes up.But will wait if somebody has better suggestions.